# how can i create get request unis ajax without expecting return value

Tags: ajax

this is my Code and when i run it i become the error parseerror. In my case i dont need a return Value, but i will just run the method.

```
Order.prototype._downloadDetails = function () {
                    
        var sServiceUrl = _oController.getServiceUrl();
        let iRoleId = _oController.getRoleId();
        let iObjectId = _oController.getObjectId();

        if (sServiceUrl && iRoleId && iObjectId) {
            _oController.doAjax (
                    sServiceUrl
                    +"/download?"
                    + "roleId=" + iRoleId
                    + "&objectId=" + iObjectId
                    , undefined
                    , "GET")
                .done(_oController._handleDownloadDetailsResponse)
                .fail(_oController._handleDownloadDetailsResponseError);
        }
    };
```

Comment: An AJAX request will always return a response of some kind. How to ignore that response depends entirely on how you're handling the request in JavaScript and doesn't involve WordPress at all.

Answer (score 0):

i have correct my Code and it works now.

```
Order.prototype._downloadDetails = function () {
                    
        var sServiceUrl = _oController.getServiceUrl();
        let iRoleId = _oController.getRoleId();
        let iObjectId = _oController.getObjectId();

        if (sServiceUrl && iRoleId && iObjectId) {
                window.open(sServiceUrl
                    +"/download?"
                    + "roleId=" + iRoleId
                    + "&objectId=" + iObjectId, '_blank').focus()
        }
    };
```